# $f([0, \pi))$ is not open in $S^1$

Tags: general-topology

Consider   $f: [0,2 \pi) \rightarrow S^1$ defined by $f(t) = (\cos(t), \sin(t))$, then $f([0, \pi))$ is not open in $S^1$.

I'm not very sure why it's not open? Does it have anything to do with the open sets in $S^1$?

Comment: It’s not open in $S^1$ for the same reason that $[0,\pi)$ is not open in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Consider the top. space $\left( {{S^1},\mathcal{O}} \right)$ where $\mathcal{O} = {\left. {{\mathcal{O}_{{\mathbb{R}^2}}}} \right|_{{S^1}}}$.